# SocketException with AmazonMQ with .NET Core 2.2

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, activemq-classic, socketexception, apache-nms

I get a `SocketException` just trying to create a connection to AmazonMQ with the NMS ActiveMQ .net nuget package.  Here is how I'm trying to connect:

```
string url = "ssl://amazoninstance:61617";
string userName = "un";
string password = "pw;

var transport = transportFactory.CreateTransport(new Uri(url)); // Error's out here
var connection = new Connection(new Uri(url), transport, new IdGenerator());
connection.UserName = userName;
connection.Password = password;
var session = connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge);
```

My brokers "Public Accessibility" is set to "Yes".  I've also opened up the inbound security groups so it should be able to receive connections from my IP.  Any input on what I might be missing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just heard back from Amazon.  I had the security groups setup to only allow all IPv6 connections.  IPv4 was still being blocked.  Fixing that resolved my issue.